# SSAS cube fact and dimension relationship

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, tabular-model

I have a cube that all the tables has one row per ID and have measure in all of them except for the calendar dimension.

When I view the measures in excel from Table 1 with attributes from table 2, I have no issues, but when I view the measures from Table 2 with attributes from Table 1 it returns the same number for each value of the attributes:

```
BillingCycle        HCD Accounts For Review
7                     4067
14                    4067
30                    4067
```

How can I overcome this issue? Does this have anything to do with the direction of the relationship between the tables?

Comment: Column (BillingCycle) is the attribute with values (7, 14, 30), the measure is (HCD Accounts For Review) with values for each (BillingCycle) is 4067.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is a typical example of a missing dimension relationship.

Yes it has something to do with the relations in your `dsv` but easy to solve with dimension relationships.

If you add a dimension to a measure group/cube/fact table the dimension relations are automatically generated based on the relations in the data source view, if a relation isn't present a dimension relation has to be created manually.

So in your example you need to go to the cube where the measure group is residing and select `dimension relationships` and define the relation between your dimension key and the fact table.

See [defining dimension relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166560.aspx) for details on how to do exactly that.

It's actually fairly obvious why SSAS would behave like that. If there is no relation between axis and figures, there is no way a slicer can have impact on the figures.

If you are using a `Tabular` model, unless it lets you add relations in both directions I fear you'll be out of luck and need to design your data warehouse better using actual fact tables and dimension tables.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. The relationship already exists between the two tables on the unique ID, if this is what you mean.

Comment: One more thing to add, my cube is a tabular model.

Comment: I wanted to show you the cube diagram, but I don't how to insert it.

Comment: @Sazan you can add a screenshot, just save it as a file and insert an image.

Comment: @Sazan I didn't think about tabular since i'm used to hearing 'model' instead of 'cube' when referred to tabular but that's my fault :)

Comment: I think the solution you have mentioned is for multidimensional model not for tabular, this issue in tabular model can be only resolved by writing some DAX queries, please correct me if I am wrong. I couldn't find an insert option.

Comment: @Sazan The last sentence adresses tabular (next time try to mention that in the original question) but in tabular you are out of luck, you need to fix your DWH design or write messy DAX

Comment: I forgot to mention that, apologies. Thanks for all your feedback.